# Verifying the equation of motion, expressions of kinetic energy and potential energy and how to examine whether motion confined to a plane or not

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

> ***A particle is moving in space such that it is attracted towards a fixed point and is proportional to the distance from the fixed point. Derive the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian of the system. Examine whether the motion of the particle is confined to a plane or not.***

I have the above question as my homework. I have tried to attempt it in the following way:

**MY ATTEMPT**

The equation of motion of the particle is given by:
$\ddot{x}=-kx$ , $\ddot{y}=-ky$ , $\ddot{z}=-kz$ ,---------(1)
where, k=proportionality constant

I assume the initial conditions as
$x=x_0,\dot{x}=\dot{x_0}$ at $t=t_0$
$y=x_0,\dot{y}=\dot{y_0}$ at $t=t_0$
$z=x_0,\dot{z}=\dot{z_0}$ at $t=t_0$

Solving (1) and using initial conditions, we get;

$x=x_0 cos(\sqrt{k}(t-t_0))+\frac{\dot{x_0}}{\sqrt{k}} sin(\sqrt{k}(t-t_0))$
$y=y_0 cos(\sqrt{k}(t-t_0))+\frac{\dot{y_0}}{\sqrt{k}} sin(\sqrt{k}(t-t_0))$
$z=z_0 cos(\sqrt{k}(t-t_0))+\frac{\dot{z_0}}{\sqrt{k}} sin(\sqrt{k}(t-t_0))$

Since, $T=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2)$ and $V=\frac{1}{2}({x}^2+{y}^2+{z}^2)$ , so
now I need to calculate the velocity by differentiating and then squaring the solution that I obtained above and put it in the expression for $T$ and $V$.
Since, $L=T-V$ and $H=T+V$ , so, after that I need to subtract and add $T$ and $V$ to obtain the Lagrangian and Hamiltonion respectively.

**MY QUESTIONS**

1. Is my procedure correct for finding the kinetic and potential energies?
2. How to do the last part of the question i.e. how to check whether the motion of the particle is confined to a plane or not?
3. Is the force in the above question a central force?
4. Do the equations of motion obtained in the the above way, the Lagrange's equation of motion and the Hamilton's equation of motion give the same result?

Comment: Which unit has k ? your procedure to find the kinetic and potential energy is not correct

Comment: @Eli k is acceleration per unit distance. Also I have assumed the particle to be of unit mass.

Comment: @Eli Why is my attempt incorrect? Where have I done wrong?

Comment: What quantity could you use to check whether the particle moves in a plane?  Hint: If it is motion in a plane, something will have a uniform direction, though may not keep the same magnitude.

Comment: @Dan Sorry, I do not know what is that quantity. Can you please tell me? Also, is my attempt to find L and H correct?